# parse html beautiful soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a html page

```
<a email="corporate@max.ru" href="http://www.max.ru/agent?message&to=corporate@max.ru" title="Click herе" class="mf_spIco spr-mrim-9"></a><a class="mf_t11" type="booster" href="http://max.ru/mail/corporate/">
```

I neeed a parse email string

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data
    string = soup.find("a",{"email": ""})
    print string
```

But it not working.
Where mistake?

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake was in using the `attrs` dict to look for elements with an email attribute that is empty. Try this instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

req = urllib2.urlopen('http://worldnuclearwar.ru')

soup = BeautifulSoup(req)
print soup.find("a", email=True)["email"]
```

To print the `email` attribute of the **first** `a` element which has an `email` attribute. If you want **all** emails, try

```
for link in soup.findAll("a", email=True):
    print link["email"]
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 599, in __getitem__
    return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'email'

Comment: @user413036 Updated again given your actual test data.

Comment: @user413036 Glad to hear it, please accept my answer if it works for you (click the tick box next to my answer)